# The `ssh-keygen` command is not installed in Arch Linux and can't find it in AUR or official packages

Tags: ssh, arch-linux

As the title says.

For some reason `ssh-keygen` is not installed on my install of Arch Linux, and I can't seem to find it on the AUR or the official packages repository.

How would I go about obtaining it?

The ArchWiki assumes you have it installed and doesn't give instructions on *how* to install it: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys

Or at least it doesn't make it obvious. If I missed it please say so. :)

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `ssh-keygen` command is part of OpenSSH (package "openssh"). That's why the article assumes you have it installed – you wouldn't be able to use `ssh` if you didn't.

Use `pkgfile (-v)` or `pacman -Fs` to find which packages contain a given file:

```
$ sudo pkgfile -u
$ pkgfile -v ssh-keygen
core/openssh 7.2p2-1        /usr/bin/ssh-keygen

$ sudo pacman -Fy
$ pacman -Fs ssh-keygen
core/openssh 7.2p2-1
    usr/bin/ssh-keygen
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. As already said:

> The ssh-keygen command is part of OpenSSH

Looks like the `openssh` package don't comes installed by default on Arch Linux. So you can install running:

```bash
sudo pacman -S openssh
```